# Как поставить объект на место другого в unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Нужно поставить объект в unity3d на место другого (те же координаты)
Как это сделать не кодом , а просто его переместить в менеджере сцен.

Думаю, я задал глупый вопрос,но удалить я уже его просто так не могу.

Comment: Руками скопировать значение `position` составляющей компонента `Transform` одного объекта и вставить их в `Transform` другого объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый возможный вариант это выделить тот объект на место которого нужно будет поставить объект, открыть вкладку Инспектор, найти компонент Трансформ, навести курсор мыши на поле Позиция и скопировать значение в поле X, далее выделить тот объект который нужно поставить на место первого - так же открыть инспектор найти компонент трансформ, навести курсор мыши и выделить поле позиции по оси X и вставить туда скопированное значение из первого объекта, (копировать вставить гор.клавишы: ctrl+c и ctrl+v), далее все тоже самое нужно проделать и с остальными осями Y и Z (менять значения можно в любом порядке, но обязательно как делал я) - как только проделаете эти операции - объект которых должен был встать на место другого объекта - благополучно должен встать туда

еще возможно вам нужно будет повернуть объект? я расскажу как это делается: нужно просто проделать все те же операции что и с полем position ..но в этом случае с полем rotation, и ваш объект будет повернуть в ту сторону что и первый объект

есть еще один возможный способ:
нужно выделить первый объект, открыть инспектор, найти компонент трансформ и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

такая манипуляция полностью скопирует пространственное положение первого объекта, далее нужно выделить тот объект который нужно поставить на место первого и так же открыть инспектор, найти компонент трансформ и:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таким образом вы вставите значения во второй объект - и тем самым переместите его в то место где стоит первый объект

если что то не понятно я могу снять подробный видео гайд

Comment: Об копировании позиции в трансформе я знал ,но вот если таких объектов 20 , то немного долго так делать.Спасибо за ответ, но кажется я просто задал глупый вопрос .